# System of roots

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\Phi$ an irreducible system of roots, $\Phi^{+} \subset \Phi$ a choose of positive roots. I have to prove that if $(\alpha, \beta) \ge 0$ for al $\beta \in \Phi^{+}$ then $\alpha$ is the highest among roots of the same lenght. I have a long way... is there a way that uses only some theorem?