# Lie algebra and enveloping algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

I have to prove that a Lie algebra over the field $k$ is trivial if and only if the enveloping algebra $U(L)=k$.

I have an idea of proof:
If $L=\{0\}$ we have that the tensor algebra $T^m=\{0\}$ for all $m \neq 0$, so we have $U(L)=k$.
We have that always exists an injection of $L$ in the enveloping algebra $U(L)$, which has dimension $1$. So $\dim(L) \le 1 $.

How can I finish my proof?

Comment: Trivial here must mean $L = \{0\}$ because if $L \neq \{0\}$ then $U(L)$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: Jes, triavial means $L=\{0\}$

Comment: @all Thanks! Always learning new things here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To finish note that it is never the case that the identity element $1 \in U(L)$ is contained in $L$ (when we think of $L$ as a linear subspace of $U(L)$) so it cannot be the case that $\dim L = \dim U(L)$ (otherwise $L = U(L)$).  Thus $\dim L < 1$.  This gives $\dim L = 0$ hence $L = \{0\}$.

The reason $1$ is not in $L \subseteq U(L)$ is because of the way $U(L)$ is constructed.  You start with the tensor algebra $T(L)$ where $L$ is in degree $0$.  Then you quotient out by the ideal generated by elements of the form $[xy] - x \otimes y + y \otimes x$.  Noteice that these elements are sums of monomials of degree $1$ and higher.  So the ideal you are quotienting by is contained entirely in $T(L)^+$, the two sided ideal of $T(L)$ generated by homogeneous elements of degree $1$ or greater.  So if $x \in L$ the element $1 - x$ does not go to zero in the quotient (it's not contained in $T(L)^+$).  So in $U(L)$ the expression $1 = x$ is not true for any $x \in L$.

Comment: Coul you explain better... I don't understan. Thanks

Comment: If you are more specific about what confuses you it will be easier to help.  Is it that you don't understand why $\dim L < 1$ finishes your argument?  Or is it that you don't understand by $1 \notin L$?

Comment: I don't understand this two claims.

Comment: I've edited my response to clear both of those up.

Comment: And why $dim(L) <1$?

Comment: Because $\dim U(L) = 1$ and $L \subseteq U(L)$ is not all of $U(L)$.

Comment: Do you any ideas for this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311363/system-of-roots

Comment: But we have tensorial algebra end not symmetric. In the symmetric algebra $x \otimes y$ is equal to $y \otimes x$. Then $L \subset U(L)$ up to isomorphism. How can I solve this detail?

Comment: Sorry, I just used the wrong word.  Everything I said above holds when you replace $S(L)$ with $T(L)$, as I've done in my edit.

Comment: And aboul the isomorphism?

Comment: What isomorphism?  What about it?

Comment: I know that $L \subset U(L)$ up to isomorphism. In $U(L)$ there isn't a concrete copy of $L$. In what sense $1=x$ is false?

Comment: In $U(L)$ there is a canonical copy of $L$.  It is the set of cosets $x + I$ where $x \in L$ is an element of $T^1(L) \subseteq T(L)$ and $I$ is the ideal such that $U(L) = T(L)/I$.

Comment: Sorry... what is $T^{1}(L)$?

Comment: $T^i(L)$ are tensors $x_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes x_i$.

Comment: What is the subject of the sentence: "It is the set of cosets...?

Comment: The canonical copy of $L$ in $U(L)$.